# Looking for an Android app that will let me organize my shopping lists

Tags: android, bookmark, wishlist

I have several features that are an absolute must. I want to be able to save products from the web (and preferably Android apps) to a categorized list (preferably with subcategories). For instance, if I find a new scarf online that I have my heart set on, I want to be able to save it to a 'Clothing' list (with the url of the page attached), under a subcategory of 'Winter Gear'. That's it.

I'm basically trying to migrate the shopping folder I have in Firefox into an easily manageable list app so I can edit it and save new products to it from my phone. It would be a major bonus if I could easily *share* a product page from within my current shopping apps (Macys, REI, etc.) to the list app as well. I will continue to look online for a solution but if someone else knows of an app that can do this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found *exactly* what I was looking for. It's called [Beans Wishlist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wish.wishlist). It has *almost*every single feature I mentioned **including the ability to save products from websites and Android apps**, so awesome! It doesn't currently let you put them into categories or subcategories, but I left feedback requesting that feature be added, so hopefully it will soon. Update: Beans Wishlist is still a viable option but I found a better app that includes cloud backup and just works better imho called [Wish Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wishexplorer&hl=en_US). It's not perfect but works for me most of the time. Sometimes it won't find the correct picture or price but both can be input manually.